# Copy native dll from NuGet package on C# project build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have few packages with native dll.

While building the project I need to copy all native dll's to an output.

At the moment I found aonly 1 solution - Post-Build event - xcopy. But the problem is that I need to update packages path (with a new version) after any update

Answer (score 0):

The inly one good solution i found - to embed narive dll's as resource and add some kind of initialization or static constructor to DLL interface classe(s) that will save resources to the current folder.